# Embarcadero Rad Studio 10.1 and 10.2 Missing Android Tools

Tags: android, rad

My installations of Berlin 10.1 and Tokyo 10.2 included the Android SDK, but do not include the Android Tools in the "All Programs" list as they are supposed to be according to the DocWiki.  Any ideas on why this might occur and how to fix it?

I am trying to connect to my Android device, but can assign it do to the lack of "Android Tools"

Comment: Same problem here :(

Answer (score 0):

It should be in "C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\19.0\PlatformSDKs\android-sdk-windows" for RAD Studio 10.2.

If it is not, just download and install the android sdk, then set it up in RAD Studio, under Tools menu, Options, SDK Manager, using the "Add" button.